# Pointer to a constant array

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

I have `struct A` and following code: `A *const *ppA` What does this code mean? It is a pointer to a constant array? I'm not sure so I asked this question here

Comment: This is a pointer to a const pointer to a struct A  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-int-const

Comment: Where do you get the array from?  There's no array in the declaration.  (Of course, any pointer _might_ point to the first element of an array.  Or not.)

Comment: @JamesKanze I'm using it as a pointer that point to the first element of an array so that's why :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`const` and `volatile` qualify the type immediately before them (unless they appear at the beginning, in which case they qualify the type immediately after them); so you can read this from right to left:

`ppA` is a (non-constant) pointer to a constant pointer to a (non-constant) `A`.

There's no way to tell from the declaration whether it might be used to point to a single object, the first of an array, or no object at all.